# Coding in MVC architecture

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, jstree

I need to represent a complex model in MVC (model view collection) architecture. I'm using `backbone.js` with `jsTree`.

I'm retrieving data from the server as `JSON` and making a tree with it. For displaying the tree I'm using jQuery's `jsTree` plugin. The data represents file system architecture of some remote system.

The problems I'm encountering are these:

1. *Should I create two models?* One representing directory and one representing file because there can be more files inside the directory.
2. *How can I attach the view with the UI?* I want to listen to all the events and do some server side action depending upon them because the view is being dynamically made by the jsTree plugin.
3. *If I make 2 models do I need to make 2 collections?* Would a singe one would do because ids in the full set of all the models will be unique?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you mean "*model view* **controller**", as that's what MVC stands for in the wider world. The controller is basically the answer to question #2.  I don't use backbone, but I notice they do distinguish between `Controller` and `Collection`.  http://liquidmedia.ca/blog/2011/01/backbone-js-part-1/

Comment: they dont use the name "controller" even once on their site. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: @Pav Sharma: WRONG.  Go back to that page and just type "controller" in your browser find.  Probably you want to start with the section *References between Models and Views*, which is where a controller comes in, and the word "contoller" is used specifically there.  There are obviously `Controller` classes in backbone, they are explicitly referred to.  Maybe you just need to do some reading about the tools you hope to use...

Comment: @goldilocks please read the section "How does Backbone relate to "traditional" MVC?" in the same web page.. i program using asp.net mvc  and prettry thru with the MVC architecture. i know what im reffering to here.. in backbone.js the "C" of "MVC" stands for "collection" and work of controllers is done by views

Comment: That paragraph (and the other one I pointed to) are making a distinction between using *a model and a view*, and *a model, a view, and a discrete controller* ("If it helps any, in Backbone, the View class can also be thought of as a kind of controller").  AFAICT, a collection is part of your model.  Unless you have seen the phrase "model view collection" used explicitly somewhere (I don't), do not confuse yourself in this way.

Comment: From the "intro to backbone" link in my first comment: *"There are five main prototypes in Backbone. [...] [3] Backbone.Controller – More or less exactly what you’re thinking."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory and file really represent the composite design pattern. You could have two models (`File` and `Directory`) but then use polymorphism to do something like `this.getContents()`.

I don't have much experience with backbone, so can't advise on point 2 or 3. (I suggest that you split these into other questions.)

Comment: though a nice idea.. i dont think i would like to do something like this. as this might create confusion as to what will be returned. after a function is called and ill have to check on every function call the type of objet on which ill be calling it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is coming late to the game, but you could do yourself a huge favor and draw out a design first in some kind of UML app like Astah Community. That will help you identify the objects and the relationships between the objects and make your coding so much easier.